# Truststore setup for gradle plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using a gradle plugin from a trusted artifactory. I am facing a problem that truststore is not getting picked up while running gradle build through IntelliJ.

I have tried to set it up from three below mentioned places but there is no luck:

1. gradlew

   DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore={path to truststore}

This works from command line with command: ./gradlew build 
but not from IntelliJ
Note: Using default gradle wrapper as recommended by IntelliJ

2. gradle.properties

   systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore={path to truststore}

This also works from command line but not from IntelliJ

3. Gradle JVM Options in IntelliJ

This does not work from IntelliJ

What can be the issue, any suggestions?

EDIT: gradle distribution url is also from a trusted artiactory and my hunch is that's why nothing is working.

Comment: You can check that the property has been passed by printing in in build.gradle, e.g. `build {
    doLast {
        println(System.out.print(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")))
    }
}`. When I set it in Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle VM options** I see it is printed for me. Do you see it? What exact error do get?

Comment: Did you fix this, and if so, how? We are facing the same problem with sbt, i.e. we need to get the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` param on the sbt command line inside IntelliJ.